# Android setSound - cannot get Uri of file

Tags: android, push-notification, capacitor

I've seen many articles on how to perform the setSound part of this but as yet I have been unable to simply reference the file I would like played. I am using Capacitor 4 and so the file I wish to play maybe stored in a different place than a native app.

Below is the file structure of the application and I would simply like to load the "FinalCountdown.wav"

[image: Application structure]

```
Uri sound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/assets/public/assets/sounds/FinalCountdown.wav");  //Here is FILE_NAME is the name of file that you want to play
      File file = new File(sound.toString());
      Log.w("[PUSH NOTIFICATION]","File Check");
      if(file.exists()){
        Log.w("[PUSH NOTIFICATION]","FILE FOUND at " + sound.toString());
      }else{
        Log.w("[PUSH NOTIFICATION]","File NOT FOUND!!! at " + sound.toString());
      }
```

The check always logs (package name obfuscated)

```
W/[PUSH NOTIFICATION]: File Check
W/[PUSH NOTIFICATION]: File NOT FOUND!!! at android.resource://**********/assets/public/assets/sounds/FinalCountdown.wav
```

For completeness I have the code below where I add the sound to the notification channel

```
AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
        .build();

channel.setSound(sound, audioAttributes);
```

I realise this must be really simple so any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I am grateful for all the comments and suggestions but would it be possible for a complete solution. I ask not because I am lazy but because as an Angular developer - I am using Capacitor and so know nothing of Android development and a single line suggestion here and there doesn't give me the whole picture. Also when I paste the file in to the res folder - it plays when starting the Android project! so odd

**FUTHER UPDATE:**
I have added the file to the res/raw folder
[image: File explorer]

I tried the suggested:

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("finalcountdown.wav");
catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this produced a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: finalcountdown.wav" exception

I also tried referencing the file with the suggested:

```
channel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.packageName + "/$soundRawId"), audioAttributes)
```

But I just got silence - I wasn't sure if the path would have included the "raw" part but this didn't make a difference.

Comment: You cannot use the File class for files in assets resource. And already the uri you build is wrong. Use the assets manager instead to open an inputstream.

Comment: Do not put yet an assets directory in assets.

Comment: Sorry - I added the file code as a naive way to check whether Android was able to find/reference the file. As this is a capacitor application I don't seem to have any option to place files anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

Can use :

after save inputStream to internal storage and using.

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = assetManager .open("FinalCountdown.wav");
```

Comment: You forgot the subdirs.

Comment: How can I use the InputStream? The channel.setSound method only accepts a Uri and AudioAttributes

Comment: Then you first make a copy to storage and then use FileProvider to serve your file. You can also extend ContentProvider to serve directly from assets. And only ur? Then why did you try with File class?

Comment: Sorry to be naive but as an Angular developer using Capacitor my knowledge of Android Java/Kotlin is almost non existent. I used the File class as a simple way to see if Android was able to find the file as I wasn't sure if the fault was with how I was assigning the sound to the notification. As the file are "included" in the project - why can they not be reference directly - surely they are already in the storage?

Comment: They are in the storage but they are still packed in your apps apk file which is in the storage. They are resources and have to be extracted from your apk file at runtime. The assets manager will do it for you giving you an inputstream to read from

Answer (score 0):

Put file sounds to res/raw, then use

```
channel.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                        + context.packageName + "/$soundRawId"), audioAttributes)
```